# Upgrade BI server to 2014 and stay on 2008r2 with the database engine server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, upgrade, sql-server-2014

We would be happy to upgrade our SQL Server environments to 2014, but we have a tight budget for next year.

Our BI server (SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition, that is used only for BI purposes) is located separately from the Production Database server (SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition). The BI server contains our SSIS and SSRS packages and reports.

I was wandering whether it's possible to have a configuration where the BI server will have SQL Server 2014 (Standard of Business Intelligence) but the database server itself will remain on 2008.

Thanks for your answers,

Roni.

Comment: This question kind of confused me.  Are you saying you have a BI and a PRODUCTION server, and you want to upgrade the BI server to 2014?  When you say 'BI server' do you mean a SQL server that is only purposed for BI?  Just trying to make sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasn't clear enough. The BI Server is a SQL Server that is only used for SSRS/SSIS purposes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is too generic. As we don't know what reports you are running on your SSRS/SSIS instance and what features you are using, we will be unable to answer your question. You will have to rig up a test environment where you can test the features of your Reports and Integration Services and then proceed to upgrade your environment. Currently this question is too generic to be answered satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

If your setup involves your BI server being standalone and the report server database is being hosted on the BI server and not the production database then yes upgrade to 2014. You should consider looking at the new deployment methods with SSIS, very cool stuff.

If your setup involves:

- your BI server only houses the Integration Services and Report Server binaries
- your SSRS report database is being hosted on the production server
- your IS packages are file system

Then the below would apply.

---

With SSRS that would be a supported setup if you installed SQL Server 2014 SSRS on your BI server. You can view the [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157285.aspx) that shows the supported database instances to house the SSRS databases.

> SQL Server is used to host the report server databases. The SQL Server Database Engine instance can be a local or remote instance. The following are the supported versions of SQL Server Database Engine that can be used to host the report server databases:

- SQL Server 2012
- SQL Server 2008 R2
- SQL Server 2008
- SQL Server 2005

SSIS 2014 is another beast though if you want to actually use the new features that come with it for management: [SSISDB Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479588.aspx) or [Project Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213290.aspx) (which requires the SSIDB Catalog). You would have to have a SQL Server 2014 database instance in order to configure all this. The only thing you would be able to do with this type of setup would be a file system deployment, anything else I think is going to require the database engine to be at the same major version.

Answer (score 0):

But of course.  I suspect that you want to upgrade to the SQL Server 2014 Business Intelligence edition, since that is more frugal than Enterprise. But the BI edition does include the SQL Server database also in the license.

Are you wanting to upgrade the BI server in order to get the latest BI features?

SQL Server 2014 can certainly pull information from earlier editions of SQL Server for processing locally. Or the tools can read directly from the 2008 server.